# Getting different value in manually eneterd/calculated

Tags: angularjs

I have two input boxes: length and breadth.

The area is calculated is  l*b and based on this I am calculating the result. My result that is Area to be treated:= `(sum +(sum *0.05))`.

It's working fine, but the problem is when I am entering area manually without length and breadth, I am getting different result. Both result must be same, even if I enter the area manually.

eg, if I enter the area as `1`, the output is `10.05`.

If I enter the length as `1` and breadth `1`, the area is 1 so the output is `1.05` *which is correct*.

I need `1.05` whether I enter the length and breadth or just the area alone.

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope) {

     /* Start constants declaration*/
     $scope.constant = {coeff : "0.003"};
     /*End constants declaration*/

     /*Start user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 0, b2 : 0}];
     $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
          var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo, l2 : 0, b2 : 0});

     };

     $scope.removeChoice = function () {
          var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          if (lastItem !== 0) {
               $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
          }
     };

     $scope.sum = function () {
          var sum = 0;
          angular.forEach($scope.choices, function (choice) {
               sum += choice.l2 * choice.b2;
          });
          return sum;
     }
      $scope.Getarea = function () {
                $scope.total = document.getElementById("total").value;
                //totalsum =$scope.total;
                //alert(totalsum);
            };
            
    $scope.$watch($scope.sum, function (value) {
        $scope.total = value;
    });

     /*End user input values and Function to add/remove input fields*/

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="area.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class = "col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 center-output " ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl" >
     <h3 class="text-red bottom-line-thick">Antitermite treatment Calculator</h3>

     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-2">
          <div class="heading"><b>Step: 2</b> - Enter your <b>Requirement</b></div>

         <!--Start Input calculation-->

          <div  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bottom-line">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-red" aria-label="Left Align" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-right-gap  btn-red" aria-label="Left Align" ng-click="addNewChoice()">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
               </h4> 
               <div class="walls">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                         <label for="length">Length ({{data.selectedOption.name}}):</label>
                         <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="length"  ng-model="choice.l2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                         <label for="breadth">Breadth ({{data.selectedOption.name}}):</label>
                         <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="breadth" ng-model="choice.b2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                         <label for="area">Area (sq {{data.selectedOption.name}}):</label>
                         <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="total" placeholder="Area"  ng-model="total" ng-change="Getarea()">
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>  
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 step-result bottom-gap">
          <div class="heading"><b>Step: 3</b> - Material <b>Required</b></div>
          <div class="col-md-12 ">

               <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <p class="bold">Area to be treated:</p>
                    <h1>{{(total + (total * 0.05))|number:2}}<span class="small-text"> (sq {{data.selectedOption.name}}):</span></h1>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <p class="bold">ATT Chemical</p>
                    <h1>{{((total + (total* 0.05)) * constant.coeff) |number:2}}<span class="small-text">ltrs</span></h1>
               </div>

          </div> 
     </div>                        
</div> 
</div>            
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type in `ng-model=total` it will actually be treated a string. You could use `input type=number` perhaps, or you can just cast it to a number when you set the total:

```
$scope.Getarea = function () {
  // numeric cast
  $scope.total = +document.getElementById("total").value;
}
```

Since you already have `ng-model` you don't need the `ng-change` at all and you and use `input type=number` to have it work as a number or you can cast it where you actually use it.

```
{{((+total + (total* 0.05)) * constant.coeff) |number:2}}
```

Comment: ,its working fine but the problem is after giving area manually,the result is calculating but same time if we give the length and breadth its not changing,eg if i entered the area manually 100,and then if i change the length 12 and breadth 20 it must be 200,but the its showing 100 only,the problem is after giving manual area input it should reset the value if we enter the length and breadth.can it possible to reset the value or both mannually/calculated input should work???